# Check to see what item in ArrayList is smaller c#

Tags: c#, arraylist, compareto

I am trying to make my own multithreaded mergesort algorithm by using an ArrayList. I am familiar with this method in Java but trying to bring it over to c# is not working as planned. I get the following error when trying to compare two ArrayList items `Error 1   Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'object'`. I know you cannot directly compare two objects like that, in Java you can use compareTo or something like that, is there any equivalent for c#?

Here is the code causing the error in case you need it, bear in mind that I copied this from one of my Java programs that worked with integer arrays.

```
int size = (last - first) + 1;
ArrayList temp = new ArrayList();            
int mid = (first + last) / 2;
int i1 = 0;
int i2 = first;
int i3 = mid + 1;
while(i2 <= mid && i3 <= last) 
{
    if(list[i2] < list[i3])
        temp[i1++] = list[i2++];
    else temp[i1++] = list[i3++];
}

while(i2 <= mid)
    temp[i1++] = list[i2++];

while(i3 <= last)
    temp[i1++] = list[i3++];

i3 = first;
for(i1 = 0; i1 < temp.Count; i1++, i3++)
    list[i3] = temp[i1];
```

Comment: Here's a hint: Don't use `ArrayList`, use a typed list, for example `List<int>`.

Comment: Where is your `list` var declared?

Comment: Ok and how would I go about comparing two items in List<T>?

Comment: Items in a `List<T>` are of type `T`. So if `T` is `int`, then you are comparing ints like you would normally.

Comment: Since I want to make the function general I declared list as List<T> list in my function parameter, it still gives me the same error as listed above

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into the [IComparer<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx) interface. You can make a version of your MergeSort algorithm that takes an `IComparer<T>` which can be used to compare the objects for sorting. It would probably give you similar functionality to what you are used to.

You could do this in addition to defining a version of MergeSort that restricts the type to `IComparable<T>`. This way, between both versions of the function, you can handle objects that implement the interface already and also allow your users to provide a comparison for objects that don't implement it.

You could put the MergeSort in as an [Extension Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) on the `IList<T>` interface as such.

```
public static class MergeSortExtension
{
    public static IList<T> MergeSort<T>(this IList<T> list) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        return list.MergeSort(Comparer<T>.Default);
    }

    public static IList<T> MergeSort<T>(this IList<T> list, IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        // Sort code.  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think just use a SortedList of ints.

```
var sl = new SortedList();
sl.Add(15, 15);
sl.Add(443, 443);
sl.Add(2, 2);
sl.Add(934, 934);
sl.Add(55, 55);
foreach (var item in sl.Values)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);  // Outputs 2, 15, 55, 443, 934
}
```

Or else a generic List and call Sort (better perf I think).

```
var list = new List<int>();
list.Add(5);
list.Add(1);
list.Add(59);
list.Add(4);
list.Sort();
foreach (var element in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element);  // Outputs 1, 4, 5, 59
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could cast each item to `IComparable` or do an `as IComparable` and check for null (casting will throw an exception if the object instance doesn't implement the interface). But what @DavidG L suggested probably the way to go. But make a constraint on T that it must implement `IComparable`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ArrayList` is not a generic collection, so it allows to call only `object`'s methods on any item. You can use LINQ to cast to generic `IEnumerable<int>`, then you will be able to call methods on `int`, including comparing and ordering:

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
al.Add(1);
al.Add(2);

IEnumerable<int> coll = al.Cast<int>();

if (coll.ElementAt(0) < coll.ElementAt(1))
// ...
```

or:

```
var ordered = coll.OrderBy(n => n).ToList();
```

If your `ArrayList` contains objects of different types, you should use `OfType<int>` to filetr out `int`s, but the proper way would be to use a typed collection like `List<int>` instead of `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

Taking all of your suggestions into account I have come up with the following solution:

```
public static void merge(List<T> list , int first, int last) {
    int size = (last - first) + 1;
    List<T> temp = new List<T>();
    IEnumerable<IComparable> sorter = (IEnumerable<IComparable>)list;
    int mid = (first + last) / 2;
    int i1 = 0;
    int i2 = first;
    int i3 = mid + 1;
    while(i2 <= mid && i3 <= last) 
    {
        if (sorter.ElementAt(i2).CompareTo(sorter.ElementAt(i3)) < 0)
            temp[i1++] = list[i2++];
        else temp[i1++] = list[i3++];
        }

        while(i2 <= mid)
            temp[i1++] = list[i2++];

        while(i3 <= last)
            temp[i1++] = list[i3++];

        i3 = first;
        for(i1 = 0; i1 < temp.Count; i1++, i3++)
            list[i3] = temp[i1];
    }
```

Thank you for all the help, I do not get any errors anymore.